# Perl comparing md5's

Tags: perl, md5

I use the following script to get md5 of files and it works a treat as expected:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Digest::MD5;

my $file = "$ARGV[0]";
open (my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Can't open '$file': $!";
binmode ($fh);

my $md5 = Digest::MD5->new->addfile($fh)->hexdigest;
print $file, "\n", $md5, "\n";
```

<strike>What i want to do is use the script above, and then compare that `$md5` with another already known md5.</strike>

EDIT:
The idea is to check certain predefined files for validity. I already know the md5's of the "good" files, I just need to compare the known md5's with the ones obtained from this script above. I am just unsure of what to do next.

EDIT 2:
I have figured out how to push objects into the array with `push(@array, $filehandle);` now i just need to create another array with the predefined md5s, which raises my next question, is there a way to see if one entry in `array A` is the same as *ANY* entry in `array B` ?

EDIT 3:
I have figured out how to actually compare the two md5's doing this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Digest::MD5;

my $file = "$ARGV[0]";
my $file1 = "$ARGV[1]";
open (my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Can't open '$file': $!";
binmode ($fh);

open (my $fh1, '<', $file1) or die "Can't open '$file': $!";
binmode ($fh1);

my $md5 = Digest::MD5->new->addfile($fh)->hexdigest;
my $md51 = Digest::MD5->new->addfile($fh1)->hexdigest;

print "\n", $file, "\n", $md5, "\n", "\n", $file1, "\n", $md51, "\n";

if ($md5 eq $md51) {
    print "\n", "The MD5's match perfectly", "\n";
} else { 
    print "\n", "The MD5's do NOT match", "\n";
}
```

But this compares the md5 of the two args. What i need to figure out is how to compare the argv0 md5 against an entire array of predefined md5's.

Comment: also, i am not sure if it would be better to store known md5's into a  file or to incorporate the known md5's into the script itself. any insight on the best way to accomlish this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can store md5 digests in ie. `"$file.md5"` files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little script right here is exactly what i was after. This code will accept any file as an argument, then it will get the md5 digest of that file. Once it has the md5, it compares it against the entire array. My only question now would be... If i have 1200 md5's, will that slow the script down at all? The md5's i am checking are gonna be on filenames that never changes. would it be quicker to add multiple arrays, one for each filename, Then it would read the filename and search only that array. Thank you all for the help, and i am sure ill be back sooner or later. lol

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Digest::MD5;

my $file = "$ARGV[0]";
open (my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Can't open '$file': $!";
binmode ($fh);

my $md5 = Digest::MD5->new->addfile($fh)->hexdigest;

print "\n", $file, "\n", $md5, "\n";


my @array = ('d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', 'd6721344ed0cdc2e8a054a68b7ebc365', 'cee8eb94fd83f8d534bc44bf136ebaa0');
    if( $md5 ~~ @array ) {
        print "matches array\n";
} else {
    print "does not match array\n";
}
system ( 'pause' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the expected MD5 value as an argument to the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Digest::MD5;
use Getopt::Std;

our $opt_e;

getopt( 'e:' );

my $file = "$ARGV[0]";
open( my $fh, '<', $file ) or die "Can't open '$file': $!";
binmode( $fh );

my $md5 = Digest::MD5->new->addfile( $fh )->hexdigest;
print $file, "\n", $md5, "\n";

if ( defined $opt_e ) {
  if ( $md5 eq $opt_e ) {
    print "MD5 value matches. Rejoice!\n";
  }
  else {
    print "MD5 value does not match expected\n";
  }
}
```

However, this has all been done before with the `md5sum` command, so it might be better to look into that.

Comment: Updated original post to reflect where i stand.